# SFTP multiple simultaneous connections for a single user

Tags: c#, .net

I want to know if it's OK to have multiple SFTP simultaneous connections for just one user. I built a service to download / upload files to a specific SFTP server. This service has 4 tasks running, all dealing with this SFTP server and all using the same credentials. To prevent any possible issues, I created a singleton class to upload / download the files. I'm trying to separate the tasks into different stand-alone Windows services, to prevent stopping all tasks if one of them fails (this does happen, due to timeouts). Would there be any problem in doing this ?

Thanks a million.

Answer (score 5):

Some servers limit the number of simultaneous connections a single user can perform. But if the server doesn't impose such limits (or if such limits are greater than the number of concurrent connections you need) then there is no problem performing multiple SSH/SFTP connection to the same server using the same user credentials.

Actually that's what many FTP/SFTP clients do; for example FileZilla, by default, opens up to 3 simultaneous connections towards the server, all with the same credentials. One is used only for control commands, listing directories (etc), and the other 2 to actually transfer files.